# Grails many-to-many - find all objects that contain specific list of objects

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have following domain model:

```
class Recipe {
    String title
    static hasMany = [ ingredients : Ingredient ]
}

class Ingredient {
    String ingredient
    static hasMany = [ recipes : Recipe ]
    static belongsTo = Recipe
}
```

Grails created the table RECIPE_INGREDIENTS with the ingredient ID and recipe ID.

How can I get a list of recipes with passing a list of ingredients?

```
def egg = new Ingredient(ingredient:"Egg")
def milk = new Ingredient(ingredient:"Milk")
def flour = new Ingredient(ingredient:"Flour")
def apple = new Ingredient(ingredient:"Apple")
def banana = new Ingredient(ingredient:"Banana")
def mango = new Ingredient(ingredient:"Mango")


def pizza = new Recipe(title:"Pizza")
pizza.addToIngredients(egg)
pizza.addToIngredients(milk)
pizza.addToIngredients(flour) 
pizza.save()

def salad = new Recipe(title:"Fruit Salad with milk")
salad.addToIngredients(apple)
salad.addToIngredients(banana)
salad.addToIngredients(mango)
salad.addToIngredients(milk)
salad.save()
```

for example:

```
[mango, milk] return me salad
[milk] return me salad and pizza
[milk, flour] return me pizza
```

Comment: out of curiosity, have you tried `Recipe.findAllByIngredientsInList( [ milk, mango ] )`

Comment: OT that should be "Pizza with egg and milk" ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need to check whether a set of `ingredients` belonging to a `Recipe` contains a subset of the `ingredients` that you are passing. I couldn't think of a direct way using `GORM` or `Criteira` to do this. There is a possible hack to this using HQL:

```
public List<Recipe> fetchRecipe(List<String> ingredients){
    ingredients = ingredients.unique()
    Recipe.executeQuery('''
        SELECT recipe FROM Recipe AS recipe
        JOIN recipe.ingredients as ingredients
        WHERE ingredients.ingredient in :ingredients
        GROUP BY recipe
        HAVING COUNT(recipe) = :count
    ''', [ingredients: ingredients, count: ingredients.size().toLong()])
}
```

So when you execute this method with:

```
println fetchRecipe(['milk'])*.title
println fetchRecipe(['milk', 'banana'])*.title
println fetchRecipe(['milk', 'egg'])*.title
```

It will output:

```
[Pizza, Fruit Salad with milk]
[Fruit Salad with milk]
[Pizza]
```

**How it works**

- The query begins by selecting all of the Recipes which have any of the Ingredients in the ingredients list. As long as a Recipe has at least one of the ingredient it will be returned.
- This produces the side-effect of listing a Recipe for every matching ingredient it has. For instance, if a Recipe has two of the Ingredients, then the Recipe is returned two times. The GROUP BY clause makes the query filter out those duplicate listings.
- However, those duplicates are key to this hack: if the list of ingredients is a unique list, and Recipes do not have the same Ingredient more than once, then the Recipe has all of the required Ingredients if the number of duplicates is equal to the number of ingredients. And that's what the HAVING clause does by counting the number of Recipes.

Comment: Oh .. perfect answer. Thank you very much. I'm coming to study Grails and did not know how to solve it . Thank you.